# react-route display blank page

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

My problem is react-route display blank page and no error display in console or webpack. I try to delete all Router and replace by App but it show me blank page agian.

This is my main.js file.

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

import Index from './containers/Index.js'
import App from './containers/App.js'
import pollReducer from './reducers/pollReducer.js'

var reducers = combineReducers({
  poll: pollReducer
})

var store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={Index} />
      <Route path="/question" component={App} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('app'))
```

and this is my App and Index js file

```js
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        This is App page
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

This is my Index.js file

```js
import React from 'react'

class Index extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        This is asdasdasda
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Index
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: What does your index.html look like?

Comment: @Alexander  it is a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forgot to define the `history`, Use this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/question" component={App} />
</Router>
```

Comment: Thank its work, but when i insert this code `var store = createStore(reducers)` it going to blank page agian